# Loading a csv file in spark - Unwanted ' " ' value appearing in cell values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have loaded a [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkoFQ.png), then stored that as a RDD and then as a dataframe:

Running this in a spark-shell (spark version 1.6, scala 2.10.5)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType};

val schemaString="age job marital education default balance housing loan contact day month duration campaign pdays previous poutcome y"

val schema = StructType (schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

val data = sc.textFile("bankproject.csv")
val rowRDD=data.map(_.split(";")).map(d=>Row(d(0),d(1),d(2),d(3),d(4),d(5),d(6),d(7),d(8),d(9),d(10),d(11),d(12),d(13),d(14),d(15),d(16)))

val bankDF=sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

bankDF.show()
```

---

Now the first and last cell of the all the rows in the dataframe has an additional double quotes ' " ' (see [dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBrC0.png)) , what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post the output of `data.foreach(println)`? some lines would work and please don't post images. copy paste the texts.

Comment: Also, can you post the raw csv file or an excerpt (open it in a text editor, then copy)? maybe it really has quotes there, but Excel (or whatever spreadsheet program you use) hides them.